# Report Builder: Print Table Results into Different Worksheets in Excel

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report, reportbuilder

I'm using Report Builder for SQL Server 2017. My report has multiple tables which is using more than one datasources.

Is there a way to print table results into different worksheets in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, within the property section of each table there is a field called "PageName".  Set the name for each table to what you want your tab in Excel to be called.  When exported to Excel, then a separate worksheet is created for each one.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately this is still not working for me. The tables are still printed on the same worksheet.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that you need to set the PageBreak for each table, to End (except the last table).  This will break apart the data tables. into the separate tabs.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is working perfectly now! You made my day :)